# jquery add 2 textboxes and update 3rd with the sum

Tags: jquery

Here are my 3 textboxes:

```
<input id="RegistrationFee" name="RegistrationFee" type="text"
size="6" />

<input id="ThursdayDinnerFee" name="ThursdayDinnerFee" type="text" 
size="6" />

<input id="AmountDue" name="AmountDue" type="text" readonly size="6"  />
```

What I want to do is auto fill `AmountDue` with the sum of `RegistrationFee` and `ThursdayDinnerFee`. I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but `RegistrationFee` and `ThursdayDinnerFee` are auto-populated based on the selection of radio box options. I have tried this and it does not work:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    $('[name="AmountDue"]').val(parseInt($("#RegistrationFee").val())+ 
    (parseInt($("#ThursdayDinnerFee").val())));
});
```

Comment: *it does not work* - what do you mean? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Currently your code will also trigger on the user typing inside the result fiend.... What was the question?

Comment: Andrew - Sure. Textoboxes 1 and 2 both auto populate based on the radio button selection, but Textbox 3 (Amount Due which is the sum) does not populate.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browsers console? Also, it might make sense to have your result input be `readonly`.

Comment: Drew...sorry, it is readonly but was not in original code. I just edited the code. Thanks.

Comment: where is `radio button`? your question is not clear.

Comment: [Looks like it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/L014yrj4/). Note that the `change` event is called once you leave focus of your input. If you want it to change right away use `keyup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spencer seems to think the code itself isn't explanatory enough...

Your original function on change is pointless. All three inputs should be read only since they're auto-populated, you can then fire your addition and updating of the inputs on the clicking of the radio buttons. You weren't explicit on whether there were different registration fees or not but it's not terribly hard to add the code for that since it's a minor change to what I have supplied.

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="price" value="25"> Dinner 1<br>
  <input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="price" value="15"> Dinner 2<br>
  <input class="radio-btn" type="radio" name="price" value="10"> Dinner 3<br>
  <input id="registration-fee" name="RegistrationFee" type="text" value="50" readonly/>
  <input id="thursday-dinner-fee" name="ThursdayDinnerFee" type="text" readonly/>
  <input id="amount-due" name="AmountDue" type="text" readonly  />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".radio-btn").on("click", function(){
  var $value = $(this).val();
  var $registration = $("#registration-fee").val();
  $("#thursday-dinner-fee").val($value);
  var total = parseInt($value) + parseInt($registration);
  $("#amount-due").val(total);
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/ftL0y65o/
Second fiddle to illustrate multiple registration fees. Notice rather than doing the calculation twice I just set the values of the text boxes to the defaults, no point in running a calculation you don't need. https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/L45wjyk0/3/

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful. There is no explanation on what the OP did wrong.

Comment: It's helpful because it shows explicitly how to do exactly what he wanted. I can certainly write up a description but the code is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: The events do exactly the same thing, other than one being a `click` event. OP's code seems to function fine.

Comment: Well apparently it doesn't work, or he wouldn't have posted the question. I gave him a working example of what he's trying to do, perhaps he can figure out what he did wrong from that. Been reading a lot about the childish trolling behaviour in this community lately. It gets tiresome. People are trying to help, if you haven't anything positive to add then just go to the next question. You didn't even offer any help other than to state it looks like it works (which for him it obviously doesn't)

Comment: Rick - In your jfiddle example, why is the first textbox populated with 50? If that is the case, the 3rd textbox should also be 50 because the 3rd textbox is the addition of the first 2.

Comment: Rick...you are correct, it does not work or else I would not have posted it :-)  I appreciate the help

Comment: eh, I didn't do the addition on load, that's all. Simple enough fix. @dr1054

Comment: There are a couple of options for the fix. The easiest, if the registration fee is the same for everyone, is to set the 2nd box to 0 and the third box to 50 as default values. If the registration is different let me know and I'll update the answer

Comment: @dr1054 Updated the answer to include multiple registration fees and how I'd personally handle the boxes being populated on load (just do it in the default values of whichever radio buttons are selected on load)

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, you would need to convert the text numbers to int then add them and write the result in the amount due box. This is not tested but hopefully it gives you an idea.

```
 var regFee = $("#RegistrtationFee").val();
var dinFee = $("#ThrusdayDinnerFee").val();
var result = parseInt(regFee) + parseInt(dinFee);

if (regFee.length() >= 1 && dinFee.length() >= 1 )
{
$("#AmountDue").val(result)
}
```

Comment: Josh...is legth supposed to be length?

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Tried it...doesn't seem to work. What is supposed to trigger the AmountDue populating? The Reg Fee and Thursday Dinner Fee populate when I click the radio buttons that determine their value, but nothing drops into the AmountDue textbox. Thanks.

Comment: @dr1054 to trigger the amount to populate in the input box you can just change the if to 'if ($("#radio").is(':checked')' I did not see a radio button in your HTML.